# Python "change_presence() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<on_player_stop() done, defined at /home/pi/Desktop/EbayBot/musicbot/bot.py:413> exception=TypeError('change_presence() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(value)

  File "/home/pi/Desktop/EbayBot/musicbot/bot.py", line 414, in on_player_stop
    await self.update_now_playing()

  File "/home/pi/Desktop/EbayBot/musicbot/bot.py", line 467, in update_now_playing
    await self.change_presence(game)

TypeError: change_presence() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

My Code is:

```
async def update_now_playing(self, entry=None, is_paused=False):
    game = None

    if self.user.bot:
        activeplayers = sum(1 for p in self.players.values() if p.is_playing)
        if activeplayers > 1:
            game = discord.Game(name="music on %s servers" % activeplayers)
            entry = None

        elif activeplayers == 1:
            player = discord.utils.get(self.players.values(), is_playing=True)
            entry = player.current_entry

    if entry:
        prefix = u'\u275A\u275A ' if is_paused else ''

        name = u'{}{}'.format(prefix, entry.title)[:128]
        game = discord.Game(name=name)

    await self.change_presence(game)
```

Comment: you're not showing us the `change_presence` method, but I suspect that you forgot to declare it static.

Comment: it would be useful to see how the `change_presence()` is defined (*update question*). It seems that change_presence must be used either by: `change_presence(game)` or just `self.change_presence()`

Comment: Calling `self.` will pass 2 arguments to the `change_presence` refer to the `change_presence` and do the necessary changes and you will be fine. Add the `change_presence` code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message says, `change_presence` accepts no *positional* arguments (other than `self`). All other arguments must be passed as *keyword arguments*.

```
await self.change_presence(game=game)
```

See [the docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence). (Notice the asterisk in the function signature.)

> `change_presence(*, game=None, status=None, afk=False)`

Comment: You fixed it. Thanks man. Will mark as answer when it lets me!